# Angular cdk overlay reposition scroll strategy does not make the overlay go away if the element it is connected to goes out of the viewport

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk

Does anybody know how the  RepositionScrollStrategy works while using angular cdk overlay? In my case when I scroll the element to which the overlay is connected out of the viewport, the overlay still stays at the top of the viewport and does not go away with the element it was attached to. The demo can be seen here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-overlay-scroll-frymdg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.directive.ts

Expected behavior: The overlay should go away with the element it is attached to, when scrolled out of the viewport.